# DB2 query using CLOB needs big improvement

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Any chance the below query could ever work, given I want to search a CLOB column, 
but not for literal strings, rather for dynamic values contained in columns of
 two other tables ? 
 The several parenthesized suffixes simply mean that only
 the 'first several' characters noted are wanted from the dynamic
 columns to use in the CLOB search.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.HP_EXR_ID 
FROM db2prod.PRV_BPDE_PRV_MHG A 
,db2prod.T401ALTC B 
,db2prod.T401APFN C
,db2prod.t401ahpa D 
WHERE A.HP_ID = B.HP_ID
and   A.HP_ID = C.HP_ID
and   A.HP_ID = D.HP_ID
and   a.DBMS_LOB.INSTR(MHG_BPDE_DTA_XML_TX,c.pfn_prv_lst_name) > 0)
and   a.DBMS_LOB.INSTR(MHG_BPDE_DTA_XML_TX,c.pfn_prv_fst_name(1:4)) > 0)
and   a.DBMS_LOB.INSTR(MHG_BPDE_DTA_XML_TX,d.HP_ADDR_STR_ADDR(1:8) > 0)
and   a.DBMS_LOB.INSTR(MHG_BPDE_DTA_XML_TX,d.mn_zip_addr(1:3)) > 0)
and   a.DBMS_LOB.INSTR(MHG_BPDE_DTA_XML_TX,d.pol_rgn_code > 0)

AND B.HP_ALRT_TYP_CD IN ('G1') 
AND B.HP_ALRT_TYP_STA_CD = 'A' 
AND B.ANW_TSP_GRP = 
(SELECT MAX(BB.ANW_TSP_GRP) 
 FROM db2prod.T401ALTC BB 
 WHERE BB.HP_ID = B.HP_ID 
 AND BB.HP_ALRT_TYP_CD = B.HP_ALRT_TYP_CD);
```

Comment: Due to the name of the column it seems a XML is stored in the CLOB. Any reason why you did not want to store it in a XML column providing a more focussed search?

Comment: The style `c.pfn_prv_fst_name(1:4)` is not valid syntax for Db2-LUW at present versions. 
You can use `substr(c.pfn_prv_fst_name,1,4)` instead provided that pfn_prv_fst_name is char/varchar datatype (not a large object).
The same is true for `d.hp_addr_str_addr_(1:8)`  and `d.mn_zip_addr(1:3)` 
If those columns are themselves large-obects, use dbms_lob.substr() instead of substr.

Comment: Thanks Michael and mao. I am part of a massive IT organization, the table was designed and implemented (4) years ago, I'm stuck with it and the horrible inconvenience it represents.

Answer (score 0):

It's horribly inefficient, but you can cast your CLOB to an XML and manipulate it easier such as by using `XMLQUERY()` and `XMLEXIST()` or mapping it to a temporary table :

```
FROM XMLTABLE(
'/path_to_record' PASSING XMLPARSE(a.dbms_lob)
COLUMNS
LNAME VARCHAR(40) path '/xpath_to_element/last_name/text()',
FNAME VARCHAR(30) path '/xpath_to_element/first_name/text()',
STRADDR VARCHAR(40) path '/xpath_to_element/street_address/text()',
-- etc ...
) AS LOBX
```

See examples at [Simple column name passing with XMLEXISTS, XMLQUERY, or XMLTABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0051454.html)